# c++ pass by reference : two level deep function calls

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I have code similar to this in c++. It aborts when i try to run it. Would this type of code work ?

In the main function :

```
type* a = something
type* b = something    
func1(a,b);
```

func1 declaration:

```
void func1(type* &a, type* &b){
  func2(a,b);
  // do something
}
```

func2 is as follows

```
void func2(type* &a, type* &b){
  // do something
}
```

Will these function calls work the way it should. I should have a and b modified because they are passed by reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should if you modify 'a or 'b in 'func1 or 'func2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the global variables a and b can be changed by either of these functions, in addition to the contents of whatever they're pointing at.